# How do I resize root partition with UEFI

Tags: linux, debian, partition, ext4, partition-table

Yesterday, a message poped up in Debian, saying that my root partition is full (0 MB free) after I copied a new software under /opt. So I moved the folder back to another partition to temporarily fix the issue.

I freed some space from /dev/nvme0n1p9 using a Debian installation USB, and now try to extend the root partition using this freed space.

[image: Disk partitions]

The bios of my HP laptop does not have a "legacy" boot option, so I cannot use a bootable  GParted USB stick to increase the size of the root partition.

I search a bit and it appears that extending the root partition is tricky.

I would like to confirm a few things:

- Does extending the root partition mean pushing partitions located after this one further on the disk, or can I use the unallocated space at the end of the disk and have a root partition split in two?
- Can I just move these partitions around without consequences?
- In my case, how would you sort this out, if it's even possible?
- If it's not, am I doomed to reinstall the OS?
- Can I bypass this limit by installing new applications outside of this root partition?

OS: GNU/Linux Debian 11 (bullseye)

Thank you.

- Edit - Details of root partition usage

Following comment from @oldfred, here is the biggest folders of the root partition.

The biggest usage is for texlive but I don't want to uninstall it, if possible.

[image: Root partition usage]

Comment: With Ubuntu and lots of apps, I am using 10GB of my 30GB / partiiton, but have all data in separate data partition? What is taking so much space in /? You cannot split /, but can have some folders separate, but you already have /home & /var as partitions. You can move partitions around, but always some risk. Any interruption corrupts system, so have good backups. And backup of Windows, just in case. I might move p7 & p8 to end of drive to get them out of the way. If deleted & recreated, you have to update UUIDs in fstab or it may not boot. You just need to boot flash in UEFI to use gparted.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for your comment. I edited my post to show you usage of the root partition. Thank you for the information. I would like a detailed answer to solve the situation, because I'm not confortable with the idea of failing and losing the PC. I don't have the option of backing up the whole disk, but only personnal files, but if possible, I would like to avoid reinstalling everything

Comment: I am not familiar with texlive, is that just the app? ?omorrow when you hard drive fails are you going to post how to attempt to recover data or just have a good backup of all your data, so you can easily reinstall & restore system? Backups required if any data is important. Moving any partition with lots of data is slow and must not be interrupted or data is totally lost.  You can use gparted to copy & paste the small partitions, I think that may keep same UUID, but not sure. Always do one change to completion and reboot to make sure you have no issues.

Comment: @oldfred Yes it's just the app / engine. It contains a lot of fonts and such. See this post on the tex site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547769/144901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Does extending the root partition mean pushing partitions located after this one further on the disk, or can I use the unallocated space at the end of the disk and have a root partition split in two?

Yes, it means exactly that. A partition must always be contiguous from the beginning to the end. A LVM logical volume could use multiple discontinuous pieces of disk, but converting an existing system to LVM is not exactly trivial.

> - Can I just move these partitions around without consequences?

If your `/etc/fstab` is written to use partition UUIDs instead of their device names, or if `gparted` won't rearrange the entries in the table to match their ordering on the disk, yes.

> - In my case, how would you sort this out, if it's even possible?

(Exactly as you ended up doing, as your own answer appeared while I was writing this one.)

First, move all the partitions that are located "to the right" of the partition you wish to extend as far towards the right as you can.

After that, boot to the installed OS(s) to verify everything still works.

Then boot back to the external media to extend the root partition.

> - If it's not, am I doomed to reinstall the OS?

Not doomed at all. It just takes a bit of slow and careful work.

> - Can I bypass this limit by installing new applications outside of this root partition?

That's certainly one way to bypass it, but it might be difficult to achieve for programs installed through the OS's package manager. For third-party software, it might actually be easy.

Another possible way would be to locate some branch of the directory tree on the root filesystem that occupies a fairly large amount of space but is not essential for early boot processes, and move it to another filesystem, then create a symbolic link so that it will still be reachable using original pathnames. For example, you could easily move `/usr/share/doc` to a different filesystem:

```
mv /usr/share/doc /new/filesystem/mountpoint/
ln -s /new/filesystem/mountpoint/doc /usr/doc
```

But the more filesystems you have, the more you'll run the risk of not having the free space in the filesystem you need it. That's why it can be worthwhile to extend partitions if they are clearly too small for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and all useful information! I was getting desperate of reinstalling everything, given that I had some issues with the network adapter not recognized by Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I made the attempt using GParted from a live CD of Ubuntu and it worked as intended.

I did it in two steps:

- First, move all non-root partitions to the right, using the unallocated space
- Then, expand the root partition

I rebooted after the first step, ensuring that everything was still working and knowing that reversing the first step could be done.